# VB.NET to VB6 transcription

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I have a program that contains a 2d grid of panel objects and I just realized that the computer I need to run this program on does not use .Net4 and I cannot upgrade its framework either. Because of this, I have to rewrite the program in vb6, which was not so bad until I had to make the grid of panels... Here is the code I am using in vb2010 to make the grid and I was wondering how to transcribe this into vb6.

`Dim regionGrid(0 To 37, 0 To 37) As System.Windows.Forms.Panel`
(in nested loop)

```
regionGrid(i, j) = New System.Windows.Forms.Panel()
```

Comment: PS: tried doing Set regionGrid(x, y) = New Frame, but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get happy by moving from .Net 4.0 to VB6, but [this link](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/oreilly/windows/ron/dynamic.html) teaches you how to create a control at runtime in VB6.

As already suggested, check if you really use (and need) any .Net 4.0 feature, any if not, you could write your code to run on an older version of the .Net framework.

Answer (score 1):

Does the computer not run any version of the Framework? It will be easier to backwards in .NET than VB6.